# Should I use flash card Or USB pen drive with eBoostr (ReadyBoost)

Tags: windows-xp, usb-flash-drive, readyboost, memory-card

I have 1GiB of RAM and would like to know what kind of memory device will be best for use with eBoostr (something like ReadyBoost).

I have heard that flash cards are faster than USB flash drives. What I want to know is if flash cards have wear leveling feature and support ReadyBoost. Wear leveling feature is important to prolong the life of flash memory. Also what is no less important is high-speed random read and write of small chunks of data. One person's benchmarking experience showed that SLC flash memory performs better than MLC.

What would be better?

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother using ReadyBoost. It's almost never a good idea. Not only does it wear out extremely quickly, flash drives have nowhere near both the raw bandwidth and latency as internal RAM for several reasons including the limitations of both flash memory and the USB protocol.

tl;dr: If you want more RAM, **buy more RAM**.

Comment: Where's the +2 button when you need it?

Comment: But i multitask a lot and use same applications frequently. ReadyBoost will help me here.

Comment: @Boris: I think you might be mixing up ReadyBoost and Superfetch.

Comment: Yeah eBoostr also has Superfetch.

Comment: @Boris: Well *there*'s your problem.

Comment: What is my problem? What is so bad about Superfetch?

Comment: Will you answer me or not? At least tell me so i won't wait.

Comment: @Boris: Registry cleaners are fish oil.

Comment: What Registry cleaners have to do with this?